# How Can I Wrap an Import With JSDom?

Tags: jsdom

I have a codebase that uses the ES2015 module syntax, ie. `import foo from 'bar'`.  It also has code like this:

```
// setup.js
var foo = window.foo || '';
```

I would like to use `jsdom` to provide a mock DOM for my test environment, but I can't figure out how to wrap my imported code.  The `import` statement has to come before any code, so I can't do this:

```
import jsdom;

jsdom({
    html: '<div></div>',
    done: () => {
        import setup from 'setup';
    }
})
```

But if I leave the import at the top, where it belongs, `window` is referenced before `jsdom` can get involved:

```
import foo from 'bar'; // this uses the DOM
import jsdom;

jsdom({
    html: '<div></div>',
    done: () => () => { console.log('foo'); }
})
```

Is there any way to workaround this without changing to AMD or CommonJS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out I just needed to read the spec ... or in my case a brilliant blog that broke down the spec for me (thanks [②ality](http://www.2ality.com/2014/09/es6-modules-final.html)!)  It's true that you can't `import foo from 'bar'` inside a function, but it turns out that that isn't the only way to `import` in ES6.  There's also `System.import` ...

```
jsdom.env({
    html: '<div></div>',
    done: () => {
        System.import('setup')
            .then(setup) => {
                // code that uses setup, now JSDom-wrapped
    }
});
```

Note that if you are doing all this to run code through a test runner like Mocha, you'll need to inform your test runner to do an asynchronous wait for the load.  In other words (for Mocha) you need to use the `done` argument, like so:

```
jsdom.env({
    html: '<div></div>',
    done: () => {
        describe('foo', () => {
            it('does something', (done) => {
                System.import('setup')
                    .then(setup) => {
                        // code that uses setup, now JSDom-wrapped
                        done(); // tell Mocha we're finished
                    });
            });
        });
    });
});
```